# PayPal API: How to get Related Payments from a Root Transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I had a sale that has a Payment ID of blah1 on 11/20/2020, later on 12/5/2020 I refunded part of that payment, and it has a Payment ID of blah2. When I login to my PayPal I can see these related transactions. But from the API I can only retrieve each payment ID individually. I can't seem to find anyway of looking up one to find the other, or put more simply to find all the related transactions for a payment. Can you help?

[image]

Comment: What does `v2/payments/captures/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`  return to you ?

Comment: When I lookup the original payment ID I am able to get it back in captures with a status of partially refunded. I'll continue to look into how that payment and the refund is linked.

Thank you for the suggestion. I had assumed that captures would not work for me because this was a just a payment someone made through ebay.